# PHP mail: correct formulation of email headers on a VPS

Tags: php, email, header, vps

I've been scouring forums like this one, and others, to try and get a better understanding of how to generate emails - in this case using the `PHP mail()` function - that will work without violating accepted protocols.

The situation is that my 'agency', for want of a better word, has a website advertising services from various companies. A customer who we can call John Doe fills in an online form and the information is sent to, say, Company A. Company A can then respond to it.

There is a further twist in that my site is hosted on a Virtual Private Server. So my 'real' address might be "Agency" <info@myagency.com> but the email that's generated may actually come from <someaddress@myvpserver.com>

I should add that there is an SPF record in place.

I'm really trying to understand how the email headers can be configured such that:

- The email arriving at Company A looks like it comes from

**John Doe**  `john@doe.com`

rather than

**Agency** `info@myagency.com`

or worse,

from `someaddress@myvpserver.com`

- Company A is able to easily reply to John Doe - I don't need a copy of that
- I'd really like to capture any bounces if the email sent to Company A is undeliverable for whatever reason

I don't know if that's feasible? If it is then I'd really like to know how to configure the headers - To, From, Reply-To and so on .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2:
Add this header:

```
$headers = 'From: it@comes.fromhere' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: it@comes.fromhere' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

And 3:

```
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($mail)
{
    echo "Done!";
}
else
{
    echo "Problem while sending!";
}
```

Try that!

Comment: Thanks for this. It's useful to test whether the mail is sent but I'm not sure that this tells us if it was delivered. IOW I think there may be something else that's needed...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm allowed to answer my own question, but I've made some progress since posting which may be helpful to others. What seems to work - though more testing is required - is the following:

```
$to = 'info@companya.com';
$from = 'john@doe.com';
$sender = 'info@myagency.com';
$replyto = 'john@doe.com';

$subject = "message subject";
$msg = "message body";
$headers = "From: John Doe <$from>"."\r\n";
$headers = $headers."Sender: My Agency <$sender>"."\r\n";
$headers = $headers."Reply-To: John Doe <$replyto>";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, '-f'.$sender);
```

It seems that the optional extra parameter **'-f'.$sender** ensures that any bounce message is sent to My Agency, rather than John Doe; exactly what I wanted...;-)

Of course, this may not be the only solution and I'm still not sure that this is the correct usage of the From; and Reply-To headers, so any comments from those who know about these things - I'm just a hack - would be welcome.

UPDATE:
Since I posted the original question, a new DMARC protocol has been adopted (in early 2014) by a number of email providers. I found, for example, that some emails generated on the server were being bounced because the "From:" header didn't match the actual source, ie my domain. So, for example, if the "From:" header specified a yahoo.com address and it was detected that the email hadn't actually come from a yahoo.com server then it would be bounced. This has been done to make it more difficult for spammers to spoof email addresses, but it has had a knock-on effect.

A partial solution has been to set the "From:" header to the actual source - my email address - and to rely on the "Reply-to:" header to ensure that the reply does, in fact, go to the customer rather than to us. This has has some success but, at the time of writing, it seems that we're getting some replies that should have gone to the customer but didn't. It is as if some email providers are not respecting the "Reply-to:" header but I just can't be sure at this stage.

I make no apologies for trying to answer my own question, but I'm sure I'm not the only one experiencing these issues so I hope that a definitive solution may emerge. This, however, is the best I can do at the moment and we now have:-

```
$to = 'info@companya.com';
$from = 'john@doe.com';
$sender = 'info@myagency.com';
$replyto = 'john@doe.com';

$subject = "message subject";
$msg = "message body";
$headers = "From: My Agency <$sender>"."\r\n";
$headers = $headers."Sender: My Agency <$sender>"."\r\n";
$headers = $headers."Reply-To: John Doe <$replyto>";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, '-f'.$sender);
```

Comment: unable to add DMARC as a tag to the original question